# how to crop and straight an EL image of solar panel in Matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation, alignment, crop, preprocessor

I have EL images of a solar panel taken from EL camera I have to align ,straighten and crop the useless black parts on all sides of the el image so that I can further use the corrected image .I have to make a generalize code so that if we put any image it gets straight .

I have tried the rotation it rotated a bit but I can not crop black sides and straight it .

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. To make it short, please read [ask] and then edit your question. Right now, no one will be able to help you or suggest you anything what could help you as it is absolutely unclear what you have tried and how /where you are failing.